# Unable to convert UTC time to local time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

I am getting UTC time string from server as "8/27/2016 6:56:23 AM"

I need to convert this date to my local time zone.

```
NSString *dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
NSTimeZone *inputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:inputTimeZone];
[inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

**NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:_strLiveStreamStartTime];**

NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputDateFormatter setTimeZone:outputTimeZone];
[outputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
NSString *outputString = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",outputString);
```

The problem is when i covert server string into date it gives me null value.
Please help me to solve this. I google it and implement some solution but unable to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is `month/day...`, your date format is `day/month...`, that's the issue.
And the hour is supposed to be represented by lowercase `hh` for 12 hour mode.

```
NSString *dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
```

Comment: Actually problem is also with hour formate. in HH:mm:ss it is not working and in 12 hour formate its working. Any specific reason behind this.

Comment: No, the actual problem is the inverted day/month order. `HH` works in 12 hour mode but `hh` does not in 24 hour mode if hour > 12. It's just good programming habit to use the designated specifiers.